# Dropdown Toggle working only for alternative buttons and not all buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple dropdown buttons with the same class as they were dynamically added to the page. I want to toggle the dropdown on the clicked button and not all.

I am using `closest()` and `find()` to do that, but this works only alternatively and not for every button.

For example if I click button 1 it works and not for button 2 and it again works for button 3 and not button 4 and it goes on with dynamic buttons.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('div').find('.dropdown-content').toggleClass('show');
});
```

```css
.dropdown-content { display: none; }
.dropdown-content.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown pull-right">
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    // content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown pull-right">
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    // content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown pull-right">
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    // content
  </div>
</div>
<div class="dropdown pull-right">
  <button class="btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i> </button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    // content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code, we can't see your button 2 or 3 or 4

Comment: Also the CSS where the `show` class is defined, and any default rules.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i am adding the functionality to single button which is a part of another block. These button2 and 3 will be created dynamically when the respective block is added. I just stated button 2 and 3 as an example.

Comment: @amitchauh4n Yes, i know the toggle removes the the class name but, i clearly mentioned '$(this)', so it should add/remove only to that exclusive button and no other

Comment: As per my understanding, the issue is with closest. It finds the closest div and dropdwon for the first buttona and fails to find the closest in the second button and it goes on for all other dynamically added buttons

Comment: so you mean the div containing a button and togglable div will be added dynamically right?

Comment: @amitchauh4n yes, div containing the button will be added dynamically and hence the buttons will be added dynamically too

Comment: can you check how your code structure after dynamically generating? or you can please post the dynamically generated code blocks, issue might be with the scope of blocks.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question to include more detail. I edited it to include an executable snippet, based on the code you've provided, where you can see it works correctly and does not create the issue you describe. Can you please review it and update to give us a working example, as we cannot debug a problem which is not reproducible.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the edit and making it executable. That's how my dynamic divs are generated. But the problem i have identified is dropdown-content class doesn't toggle to show for every second button for me. That has been the issue all along, i don't get why this happens only for every second button and not all.

Comment: Thanks guys for the suggestions and inputs. I have found the error, i forgot to include this click function inside the document.ready and that seems to solve the issue. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan